# react native open gallery using image picker

Tags: reactjs, native

```
//I was not able to open the gallery by using the react native image picker


import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { launchCamera, launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker'
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker'
import { StyleSheet,Text,View,TouchableOpacity,Dimensions,Pressable,} from 'react-native'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
    
    const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width
    const HEIGHT_Modal = 250
    
    const UploadModal = ({ changeModalVis }) => {
        const [response, setResponse] = useState(null)
        console.log('res', response)
    
        const closeModal = (bool, data) => {
            changeModalVis(bool)
        }
    
        const options = {
            title: 'Select Image',
            type: 'library',
            options: {
                selectionLimit: 1,
                mediaType: 'photo',
                includeBase64: false,
            },
        }
    
        const openGallery = () => {
            ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, setResponse)
        }
```

//render .....................................................

```
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity disabled={true} style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.modal}>
                    <View style={styles.textView}>
                        <Text
                            style={{
                                fontSize: 13,
                                padding: 10,
                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                                color: '#9b9e9e',
                            }}
                        >
                            Choose an option
                        </Text>
                        
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.pressableUpperBody}>
                            <Text style={styles.text} onPress={openGallery}>  <------error on press
                                Photos
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.pressableUpperBody}>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>Capture Image</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
    
                    <View style={styles.pressableUpperBody}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={styles.pressable}
                            onPress={() => closeModal(false, 'cancel')}
                        >
                            <Text style={styles.text}>Cancel</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
```

export default UploadModal

```
//getting the following error when I press on photos onPress 
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.ImagePickerManager.launchImageLibrary')]
```

........................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to clean your app and build again, you usually have to do that after installing a library that relies on native modules.

Basically you'll have to do stuff like `cd ios && pod install` `cd android && ./gradlew clean` close your bundler and build/run your app again, sometimes you might wanna clear the cache too.

Comment: I am using expo

Comment: You might need to clear the cache and restart the bundler even if you're using expo, if that doesn't work then you might wanna check the library's repo

also make sure you install with expo install and not npm or yarn to ensure the library's version is compatible with your expo version

Comment: tried your suggestion but still same error